# Can I sue employer/manager for false promises for a raise?

Tags: united-states, employment

My manager verbally told me I was getting a raise (12/10/10)

On payday, Friday afternoon, he asked me to call him again. He advised I would not be getting the 10% pay increase at this time. When asked why, his response was that "it had not gone completely through the approval process". He's been a manager and with the company for over 10 years.

As a follow-up, I sent an email to my manager asking to clarify why I was not receiving the pay increase.

His response this time (and in writing) was that I would not be getting the raise due to my 2018 end of year review and it would not be discussed again until the managers review our 2019 EOY in March.

Note: Early 2019/when bonuses were received- mine was docked due to my 2018 review. Can they legally hold my 2018 review against a raise for 2019 also? It sounds like double jeopardy.

Comment: What's your jurisdiction?

Comment: You can sue anyone for anything, but what damages would you seek? Unless you turned down another job offer due to your expectation of a raise, it's tough to see how you're any worse off than before your manager said anything. You won't find any laws governing how private companies can conduct their internal performance reviews (aside from equal employment/discrimination laws), there's no statute of limitations that says your 2018 performance can't affect your 2019 review.

Comment: The company resides in Colorado and I’m in another state (work remotely).

Comment: It’s not a private company. It’s a large company/fortune 500z Based off the information he provided informing I had the raise, I did make payment I otherwise wouldn’t have causing hardship.

Comment: @joanna2251 By "private", Nuclear Wang meant "not government".

Comment: @joanna2251 Note that there isn't any contract here for your manager to give the raise he promised. A contract requires that both sides exchange something of value - if I tell you that I will give you $100 tomorrow, and then fail to do so, it's not a breach of contract since you're not providing anything to me. It's not a great way to handle business, but it doesn't run afoul of contract law.